# Having trouble linking QML button to C++ class

Tags: qt, c++, ubuntu-sdk, qml, sdk

First time using Ubuntu SDK and QML. I've spent the entire day attempting to figure this out but every solution that i came accross is either outdated or not well documented. I'm trying to figure out how i can link my buttons in QML to functions in C++.

My class for my function:

```
#include "terminal_launcher.h"
#include <QProcess>

terminal_launcher::terminal_launcher(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{




}

void open_terminal() {
    QProcess proc;
   proc.start("gnome-terminal", QIODevice::ReadWrite);
 }
```

My terminal_launch.h

```
#ifndef TERMINAL_LAUNCHER_H
#define TERMINAL_LAUNCHER_H

#include <QObject>

class terminal_launcher : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit terminal_launcher(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // TERMINAL_LAUNCHER_H
```

My main.cpp

```
    #include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <QString>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>
//#include "launcher.h"
//#include <QtQml>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

        QQuickView view;
        view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));
        view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
   //   qmlRegisterType<Launcher>(uri, 1, 0, "Launcher");
        view.show();

        return app.exec();

}
```

and finally my main.qml

```
    import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1

/*!
    \brief MainView with a Label and Button elements.
*/
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import Ubuntu.Components.Popups 0.1
MainView {
    // objectName for functional testing purposes (autopilot-qt5)
    objectName: "mainView"

    // Note! applicationName needs to match the "name" field of the click manifest
    applicationName: "com.ubuntu.dev.product.productname"

    /*
     This property enables the application to change orientation
     when the device is rotated. The default is false.
    */
    //automaticOrientation: true

    // Removes the old toolbar and enables new features of the new header.
    useDeprecatedToolbar: false

    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)

    Page {
        y: 76
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        title: "Home"
        Column {
            enabled: true
            anchors.rightMargin: 16
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0
            anchors.leftMargin: 16
            anchors.topMargin: 16
            spacing: units.gu(1)
            anchors {
                margins: units.gu(2)
                fill: parent
            }
        }

        Item {
            id: item1
            x: 470
            y: 327
            width: 199
            height: 50
            anchors {
               top: parent.top
               left: parent.left
               right: parent.right
               bottom: parent.bottom
             }
            Action {
                  id: action1
                  text: "Click me"
                  onTriggered: print("action!")
                  iconName: "compose"
              }

            Button {
             //   signal openTerminal()
                id: test_btn
                x: 25
                y: 8
                width: 150
                height: 35
                text: i18n.tr("test")
                checked: false
                iconSource: qsTr("")
                //action: ""

                objectName: "button"
            //   onClicked: print("hmm");
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you can only import objects, not bare functions, into QML from C++.  Thus, you need to make your `open_terminal` function into a method of `terminal_launcher`, add a `terminal_launcher` object to your QML file, and then call its `open_terminal` method at the appropriate place.

An adaptation of your code follows.  Note that I've renamed `terminal_launcher` to `TerminalLauncher` to match to Qt style.

**terminal_launcher.h**

```
#ifndef TERMINAL_LAUNCHER_H
#define TERMINAL_LAUNCHER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QProcess>

class TerminalLauncher : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void open_terminal();

private:
    QProcess proc;
};

#endif // TERMINAL_LAUNCHER_H
```

`open_terminal` is now a method.  It is tagged as `Q_INVOKABLE` so that it can be used from QML.  `proc` has been made an instance property to avoid it being garbage-collected when the method finishes executing, but the child process is still around.

**terminal_launcher.cpp**

```
#include "terminal_launcher.h"

void TerminalLauncher::open_terminal() {
    this->proc.start("gnome-terminal", QIODevice::ReadWrite);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QString>
#include <QtQml>
#include "terminal_launcher.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<TerminalLauncher>("com.example.launcher", 1, 0, "Launcher");

    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl("main.qml"));
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

The call of `qmlRegisterType` is critical, as it allows the TerminalLauncher class to be instantiated in QML.  The first argument is the module name which must be imported.  The second and third are the major and minor version numbers.  The fourth argument is the name by which this class in known in QML.  You probably want to make it the same as it is in C++, to avoid driving yourself insane, but I've made it different just to show that it can be.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import com.example.launcher 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 51

    Launcher {
        id: launcher
    }

    Button {
        x: 25
        y: 8
        width: 150
        height: 35
        text: "test"
        onClicked: launcher.open_terminal();
    }
}
```

I've greatly simplified this to show the relevant parts.  Note that I instantiate a `Launcher` object and then call its `open_terminal` method when the Button is clicked.

**termlaunch.pro**

```
CONFIG += qt
QT += quick
HEADERS = terminal_launcher.h
SOURCES = main.cpp terminal_launcher.cpp
TARGET = termlaunch
```

This project file instructs qmake to create a binary called `termlaunch`.  All of these files should go in the same directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried something similar before but qmlRegisterType doesn't work for me: main.cpp:17: error: 'qmlRegisterType' was not declared in this scope
   qmlRegisterType("com.example.launcher", 1, 0, "Launcher");
                                                           ^

Comment: Also, I'm using latest version of QT5.

Comment: And when i inclide <QtQml> The new error is main.cpp:18: error: no matching function for call to 'qmlRegisterType(const char [21], int, int, const char [9])' qmlRegisterType("com.example.launcher", 1, 0, "Launcher"); ^

Comment: The site decided to make everything between angle brackets disappear, because pasting in C++ code shouldn't be easy.  It should be fixed now.

Comment: Is there an example project i can look at for what im trying to do?

Comment: I've added the project file I used while testing.  This is on Qt5.0, but I imagine it should work on 5.4 just as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just started a new project with just your code and it works now. Marked your post as the answer! But, it doesn't open gnome-terminal (working fine when done manually through terminal). It opens firefox, xterm etc which i've tested fine but not gnome-terminal. 

Also,

Is it possible to create a terminal within a rectangle and display it's output there? Let's say if i were to run some bash script, and display the output in a rectangle window, that would be very useful!

Comment: If you're just getting the output of a command, put it into a Text element.  If you actually want terminal abilities, look at how the [Terminal App](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-terminal-app) does it.